# NSSortdescriptor, finding the path to the key I wish to use for sorting

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I am using an NSSortdescriptor to sort a collection of NSArrays, I then came across a case where the particular NSArray to be sorted contains an NSDictionary who contains an NSDictionary.
I would like to sort from the string paired with a key in the last dictionary.

This is how I would reference the string:

```
NSDictionary *productDict = [MyArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *dealerName = [[productDict objectForKey:@"dealer"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

How would I use the `dealerName` in my NSSortdescriptor to sort the array?

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:/* ? */  ascending:YES];
sortedDealerArray = [value sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDesc];
[sortDesc release];
```

Hope someone could help me a bit with how I go about sorting according to keys inside objects inside other objects:)

Thank you.

Comment: Key paths work across dictionary keys, so assuming you have an NSArray of product dictionaries, it looks like the path you want is just @"dealer.name", but I assume this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

actually warrenM is right. You can just use keypaths. @"dealer.name" should work for above.